# Why is Bitbucket diff showing diffs outside of the commit list?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Unfortunately I can't show the example here, but basically I started working on this project I got passed from a coworker. I'm the only one who's made any commits to the repo since I started working on it a week ago. Now I'm trying to summarize the changes I made so created a tag for my coworker's last commit and a tag for my latest commit. I go to compare and the commits tab is perfect, nothing but my commits that I've made in the last week. But then I go to the diff tab and there are lots of changes I don't recognize. I click on blame, and it's showing me a commit made by my coworker 2 months ago, from a commit that is definitely not in the list in the commits tab. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bitbucket bug?

edit: it gets worse. When looking at the diff it says my coworker's 2-month old commit deleted a certain file. When clicking on the commit, it turns out that 2 months ago he actually CREATED that file, the file no longer is in the repo, but there is also no commit that removed the file. This just doesn't make any sense.

2nd edit: looks like I made a mistake, I actually did make the change, but blame mode is still linking it to my coworker rather than me. Here's a sample output of the diff of another file where I made extensive changes. I can't show any code and don't want to use my coworker's full name, but his last name is Lee and I'm Zachary Hall. [image: blame mode]

Here is what the list of commits looks like, note the lack of that commit by him from November: [image]

Comment: Did he make those commits after you created the branch for your work?

Comment: Hmm potentially. The repo I'm working with is actually a fork, I thought I'd enabled synching so I'd see any updates, but looking now it appears he did make some commits to the upstream repo. Is that the expected behavior for the diff though? To show changes made in an upstream repo but give a bad commit hash for which change made it and not list that commit in the list of commits?

Comment: Also looking again not only did his commit not delete those files, but those files still exist in his latest commit, but they don't in mine. I also don't think I deleted the files. Normally this is what I like about bitbucket I can see exactly who made the changes and if I did delete them when I did. But none of my commits include deleting those files.

Comment: Yes, a diff between two branches A and B will show changes on A that are not on B and changes on B that are not on A.

Comment: Be careful how you read a diff. If your coworker added files to his branch, that will be marked the exact same way as if you delete files on your branch. The diff will not tell you which of these two scenarios caused the change. Instead, you should think of this as those files exist on their branch but not on yours.

Comment: ok sorry that's not what happened but I was wrong when I said the delete wasn't on any of my commits. Sorry I was just a bit frustrated but here's the situation: 

- Upstream repo had files a, b, and c
- I deleted those files in a commit
- My coworker has since made a commit in the upstream repo with those files still existing
- Blame mode on the deleted files links to an incorrect commit made 2 months ago

At least I'm happy that I trust the diff again, but is that not a pretty big bug in blame mode if it's saying the deletion of a file was in the commit where it was initially created?

Comment: Again, you are reading the diff incorrectly. Adding a file to branch A looks the same in a diff as removing the file from branch B. The diff will not tell you which of these actions caused the change.

Comment: I'm comparing two files on the same branch on my downstream repo. In fact my understanding is the upstream repo shouldn't even be relevant in performing this diff, as whether I failed to turn on fork synching or whether there would be a merge conflict or whatever, his commit in the upstream repo has not made its way to mine where I'm performing the compare. There are no commits on the commit list of the compare that were not authored by me.

Comment: Just made an edit with images, does that make sense?